# UITabBarController image iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbar, uiappearance

I created a `UITabBarController` with storyboard for iOS5. I don't have the `UITabBar` declared in my ViewController and I can't set background image for tab bar.

```
UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBackground.jpg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
// Set background for all UITabBars
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
// Set background for only this UITabBar
[[tabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to designate `tabBarController` as an IBOutlet property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

Then wire them up in the Connections inspector in Interface Builder, and you'll be able to use your code as shown.

[image]

Comment: This is correct, without an outlet to the UI component you want to change, you won't be able to change it.